# How to disable automatic multiple cursors for HTML in VSCode

Tags: html, angularjs, visual-studio-code

I'm a little annoyed with this, but VSCode inserts automatically cursors when i stand over a html tag.
So i wanna paste some attribute like class="something" in the  tag and ended up writing things like:

`<div class="something"></div class="something">`

or

`<div class="something"></div </div>>`

is there a way to disable those automatic cursors?
Thanks

Comment: See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_41.md#html-mirror-cursor

Comment: God bless you, finally I could disable it, thanks so much for your answer. I'm curious, do you like that feature?

Comment: I don't really use it but I think it was a much-requested feature from other editors.  But if you are not going to use it it can be pretty annoying and surprising.  The default probably should have been to be off.